# Javascript's "this" pointing to wrong object inside lambda given to array.map

Tags: javascript, dictionary, scope, this

```
function myClass() { 
    this.nums = [1,2,3]; 
    this.divisor = 2; 
}

myClass.prototype.divideNumsByDivisor = function(){
    return this.nums.map(function(num) {
        return num*this.divisor; 
    });
}
```

`myClass.divideNumsByDivisor()` was suposed to multiply each number on it's member variable `nums` to the value on it's member variable `divisor`.

This is not working because the function `function(num) { return num*this.divisor; }` is pointing this to a wrong object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), the 2nd argument to `.map(fn, thisArg)` is what you want the `this` ptr to be set to when the callback function is called and it will be set to the global object (e.g `window`) if you don't pass the 2nd argument.

So, you can make your example work like this:

```
function myClass() { this.nums = [1,2,3]; this.divisor = 2; }
myClass.prototype.divideNumsByDivisor = function(){
    return this.nums.map(function(num) { return num*this.divisor; }, this);
}
```

Comment: I was not aware of that. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define a reference to your instance in the scope then get it later inside a different instance. Update your method to this

```
myClass.prototype.divideNumsByDivisor = function(){
    var me = this;
    return this.nums.map(function(num) { return num*me.divisor; });
}
```